# req.body value is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My req.body shows {} always even though I am using body-parser in my code

**user model**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        index:true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**routes**

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {currentUser} = require("../controllers/user");

router.post('/current-user', currentUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**Controllers**

```
const User = require("../models/user");

exports.currentUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {email} = req.body
    console.log(email)
    // console.log(req.query)
    await User.findOne({email}).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            // console.log(user);
            return res.status(401).json({
              error: 'User not found!'
            });
        }
        res.json({
            data:"SUCCESS"
        })
    })
}
```

I am getting an error: *user not found* even if the email id exists.
If I console.log(req.body)
=> **Output:**
`{}`
console.log(req.body.email)
=> **Output:**
`undefined`

Please help me fix this.

Comment: what are you sending in request?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use bodyPrser() middleware.
You can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
npm i body-parser --save
```

Then, in your server.js or app.js file

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(router()); //your user defined router middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //this is a bodyparser middleware to read/extract  the 
                           //data from req.body
```

Comment: I am using body-parser already. `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "2mb" }));` but it shows body-parser is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use body parser its already deprecated, since you are already using express there is a built in middleware for body-parser like

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

this will do work of body-parser.

Other thing, can you tell us what are you sending in request since it is a post request and you might be sending an empty object thats why you are getting **{}** in **req.body**?

I can see you are extracting email from it but if you can provide sample request, it will definitely help.